# В чем разница между pageX/Y, clientX/Y, screenX/Y в Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Примеры с некоторыми визуальными оформлением   будут очень полезны.

Примечание переводчика:

Этот топик был отмечен на enSO как дубликат вопроса:
 [What is the difference between screenX/Y, clientX/Y and pageX/Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9262741/7394871)

Действительно заголовок почти на 100% совпадает, но содержание ответов намного уступает, на мой взгляд, переведенным ответам с enSO в этом топике.
Они более развернутые, с хорошими графическими иллюстрациями, с интерактивными примерами.
Поэтому и был выбран именно этот топик для перевода. И у нас на ruSO подобные вопросы задавались не раз, что говорит об интересе к данной проблеме.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса: [What is the difference between pageX/Y clientX/Y screenX/Y in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9262741/7394871)
 от участника  [@Inquisitive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168904/inquisitive)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262741/what-is-the-difference-between-pagex-y-clientx-y-screenx-y-in-javascript/17704999#17704999

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Итерактивный пример**

[jsBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/avupid/3/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### CLIENT → The Browser window

`clientX` и `clientY` = значения `(px)` положения мыши относительно границ `viewport` экрана браузера

<sub>**Tip:**

Даже, если вы прокручиваете документ, значения будут всегда одинаковые</sub>

### PAGE → Весь документ

`pageX`, `pageY` = значениям в (px), положения курсора мыши, относительно левого, верхнего  угла документа.

<sub>**Tip:**

Если вы прокручиваете документ, например вертикально `pageY` значение изменяется, потому что это новая верхняя позиция курсора мыши внутри вашего элемента.

Также стоит отметить, что:

`event.pageY - event.clientY === document.documentElement.scrollTop`

( или jQuery's `$("html, body").scrollTop()` )</sub>

### SCREEN → *Ваш экран*

`screenX` и `screenY` являются значениями (`px`) текущей позиции курсора мыши относительно **физического дисплея**.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [What is the difference between pageX/Y clientX/Y screenX/Y in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704999/7394871) от участника  [@Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

### Визуальные подсказки представляют:

[image: yellow] **Screen** → Полный экран монитора (`screenX/Y`)
*Позиция всегда будет относительна к окну просмотра физического экрана.*

[image: Blue] **Client** → Клиент viewport браузера (`clientX/Y`)
*Если вы кликнете в левом верхнем углу,то значение всегда будет(0,0) независимо от  `scroll position`.*

[image: Red] **Document** → Полный документ / страница (`pageX/Y`)
Учтите, что `pageX/pageY` событие `UIEvent` объект [не стандартизован][1].

**Все значения в пикселях.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705548/7394871) от участника  [@user1693593](ссылка на профиль).</sub>