# Как конвертировать screen координаты в пространство документа в масштабированном SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Я использую плагин svg jquery Keith Wood, а не canvas HTML5.

Я определяю свое изображение svg таким образом, чтобы масштабировать мое изображение треугольника svg,  чтобы оно соответствовало его контейнеру div:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 299 215" >
    <g>
    <polygon points="1,1 299,1 149,210" fill="blue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0" class="votenow"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Но как мне тогда сопоставить системы координат? 
Я хочу зафиксировать местоположение мыши в некоторой точке над треугольником и нарисовать окружность в этих координатах X Y, но круг рисуется в другом месте, потому что системы координат не совпадают.
Таким образом например, круг рисуется из точке `10,10`, но, похоже, он реально будет в `50,60`
Окончательное решение: с помощью плагина JQuery, - нарисуйте круг и `getScreenCTM()` для вычисления точек.

Я не смог понять, как это сделать, используя только плагин.

```
$('#cvtriangle .tri').on( "click", function(e) {
    jqsvg = $('#cvtriangle').svg('get');
    svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = e.clientX;
    pt.y = e.clientY;
    pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    jqsvg.circle(pt.x, pt.y, 5, {class: 'vote', fill: 'white', stroke: 'white', strokeWidth: 2, cursor: 'pointer'});
});
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do you convert screen coordinates to document space in a scaled SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22183727/7394871) от участника  [@Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2139809/jon).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/22183727/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Если вы вызовите функцию `getScreenCTM()` для элемента SVG, она вернет матрицу преобразования, используемую для преобразования координат документа в screen координаты.

Вам нужна матрица преобразования для другого направления, поэтому вызовите `inverse()` для объекта матрицы.

`var transform = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();`

Теперь вы можете преобразовать точечный объект, чтобы выполнить окончательное преобразование:

`pt = pt.matrixTransform(transform);`

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x"),
    y = document.getElementById("y"),
    svg = document.querySelector("svg");

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = evt.pageX;
    pt.y = evt.pageY;
    pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

    x.innerHTML = pt.x;
    y.innerHTML = pt.y;
}, false);
```

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <svg version="1.0" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    x = <span id="x"></span><br/>
    y = <span id="y"></span>
 </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How do you convert screen coordinates to document space in a scaled SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22185812/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: я так и не понял, для чего эта функция ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Функция используется  для преобразования координат документа в screen координаты. Вот этот топик почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653699/28748

Comment: вроде бы, если svg сделать фиксированным и у боди убрать внешние и внутренние  отступы то координаты совпадают

Comment: @MaximLensky не могут совпадать, так как screen это физический размер монитора, а документ это клиентская часть, которая всегда меньше

Comment: хм....спорть не буду

Comment: @MaximLensky это так же справедливо для вложенных групп, к которым применены трансформации, таким образом можно узнать какая конкретно координата под мышкой, с учетом трансформаций, которые применены.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Для этой задачи, использование метода `getScreenCTM()` очень полезно.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" onload="
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var cx = c.cx.baseVal;
    var cy = c.cy.baseVal;
    var svg = this;
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    svg.onmousemove = function(e){
        point.x = e.clientX;
        point.y = e.clientY;
        var ctm = c.getScreenCTM();
        var inverse = ctm.inverse();
        var p = point.matrixTransform(inverse);
        cx.value = p.x;
        cy.value = p.y;
    };
">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow"/>
    <circle id="c" r="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How do you convert screen coordinates to document space in a scaled SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22185664/7394871) от участника  [@defghi1977](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988795/defghi1977).</sub>